# Add list of users to AD group based on headers in CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I am trying to make a script to add users to the AD groups based on header, the CSV looks like this:

```
Group1  Group2  Group3
UserA   UserC   UserA
UserB           UserC
```

The closest script I find is below, but this based below format, which is little different..

```
Group             Accountname
group1            user1
group1            user2
group1            user3
```

```bsh
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$list = Import-Csv ".\Bulk_Import.csv"

foreach ($user in $list) {
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $user.Group -Member (Get-ADUser $user.Accountname)
}
```

Is that possible for script to add users based on my format, and ignore error if user is already in the group?

Comment: SO is not a place where we rewrite scripts you found somewhere else according to your requirements. What have you tried to make this work? What *specific* problem in your code do you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$list = Import-Csv ".\Bulk_Import.csv"

ForEach ($Entry in $List) {
    $Entry.PSObject.Properties | Where {$Entry.($_.Name)} | ForEach {
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $_.Name -Member (Get-ADUser $Entry.($_.Name))
    }
}
```